# Git diff show only files that only have a particular change

Tags: git

Is there a way to get git diff to show me only the files that have *only* a particular change?

My use case is I want to discard changes to config files where only the `uuid` property has changed.

Comment: no built in way AFAIK, I was thinking of the `-G <pattern>` option but it looks like it won't help much in your case. You can try to script your way out of `git diff -U0` (or `git diff -U0 -G uuid`) and scan for files where the diff consists of _only_ such lines.

Comment: Yes, I was expecting some scripting. I was wondering whether filtering first for files in the diff that only show one line change would be a start.